# /var/run/redis/redis.pid exists, process is already running or crashed

Tags: redis, crash

Redis went quite on me.

```
user@mycomputer:~$ redis-cli

Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
```

I try to restart the service by doing this

```
sudo /etc/init.d/redis_6379 stop

/var/run/redis/redis.pid exists, process is already running or crashed
```

But no luck. Logs didn't show an error as well.

Answer (score 5):

Got it fixed by backing up the redis.rdp file mine is located at

> /var/lib/redis

check your config file "/etc/redis/redis.conf" for the rdp file's location and do this

```
sudo mv /var/lib/redis/redis.rdp /var/lib/redis/redis_backup.rdp
```

Then recreate the the redis.rdp file

```
sudo touch redis.rdp
```

Run the redis-server with the conf and it should work

```
 sudo redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Comment: Did you figure out why this happened and did you manage to restore your data or are you just running redis as a cache?

Comment: I couldn't figure out why this happened and yes I am using redis as a cache store. although I was able to restore my backup from  redis_backup.rdp.

Answer (score 5):

**Get it fixed in a tidy way:** Recreate the the redis.rdp file as suggested here in one of answer, will purge all the cache recorded so far and redis will start up fresh with no cache data.

This is a warning message to notify system crash / improper shutdown: "/var/run/redis/redis.pid exists, process is already running or crashed"

> Just **delete /var/run/redis/redis.pid file** and **restart the server again**.

**Note**: You might have lost latest cache changes due to untidy shutdown, which weren't flushed into the disk. This data loss can be minimized using frequent disk flush configuration in redis conf file(in my case it is @/etc/redis/6379.conf)

```
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
Or try AOF persistence, more details [here][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you installed redis, the pid can be found on /var/run/redis_6379.pid.

What happened is that redis crashed, but the pid is still there. So you just have to delete it.

`sudo rm -f /var/run/redis_6379.pid`

Then start redis again:

`sudo /etc/init.d/redis_6379 start`

If you can't find it, I suggest installing redis "more properly". Follow redis quickstart guide in the `Installing Redis more properly` section.

You can find it here:
https://redis.io/topics/quickstart

Answer (score 1):

Run the redis-server with config.

```
sudo redis-server redis.conf
```